# .htaccess: How do I rewrite a file URI to omit the extension and parent folder in a redirect?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a working .htaccess file that redirects a requested QR code image to a script that generates the image. When redirecting, it delivers the subdirectory and file extension from the URL that I want to remove, so that only the ID number will be delivered as an argument.

Example request (not a real working link):

http://www.mywebsite.com/qr/access-code/1234567.png

Current .htaccess file example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /qr/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/access-code/"
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ access-code.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What it sends to the script:

access-code/1234567.png

I want only the following to be sent to the script:

1234567

I'm currently cleaning this up using PHP, but may I alter the RewriteRule and/or  RewriteCond to clean it up before it reaches PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `\/(\d+).png$`

**Explanation:**

- This will match and capture in first group the `digits` appearing after a `/` slash and before `.png`.

Your code will be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /qr/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/access-code/"
RewriteRule \/(\d+).png$ access-code.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL6hT9/2)**

Comment: @ChristopherStevens: Glad it did. If you notice Regex demo version 1, it took 800+ steps. But this one took about 30 steps.

Comment: That's excellent! Thank you for showing me the way, and for referencing a great tool. I'll be working with the regular expressions 101 website a lot moving forward.